# Не запускается grunt-php

Tags: php, grunt

Установил grunt-php вроде бы нормально, никаких ошибок не появлялось.

А вот при запуске такса у меня появляется такая вот ошибка:

> Warning: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "php
>   --version" "php" ?? ?????? ???????? ??? ????? ????????, ??????? ?????? ??? ???????? ????.

Что бы это могло быть?

Comment: не имел с ним дел, но что-то подсказывает, что для его работы в системе нужен установленный php. 'php -v' то отрабатывает из консоли?

Comment: Сейчас попробую установить, как установлю, отпишу

Answer (score 2):

Проблему решил, установил php 5.6.18 и прописал путь к php.exe

```
php: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            port: 8010,
            base: 'app',
            bin: 'C:\\PHP\\php.exe'
        }
    }
}
```